# Error:Unable to start the daemon process.Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap

Tags: android, gradle, daemon

Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap

1. Invalidate Catches And Restart
2. Rebuild
3. Close The Project And Start It Again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for **1572864KB** object heap.

To solve This Error You Have To Change Only Heap Size Which Is Define In Gradle.Properties file. You Have To Change The HeapSize To **1024m** And **Rebuild** the Project, If The Error Is Not Solved Then You Have To **Close The Project And Rebuild It**.

For Video Tutorial See Below Link [SOLVED : Unable To Start The Daemon Process In Android Studio](https://youtu.be/rEVWb_8XmLU)

Comment: not working for gradlew wrapper in intellij idea 2019.1.1 (ultimate edition.)